# Specific term for a diet or lifestyle, restricted from consuming products of live animals (e.g. eggs, milk, honey)?

Tags: single-word-requests

**I'm looking for the specific term, that means a restriction in ones diet of not eating the products of living animals - without any other restrictions.**

That is, somebody who would object to eating eggs, milk or honey (which were produced while the animal is alive), but would not object to eating flesh, meat and bone (which are taken from an animal that has been slaughtered).

**Example sentence:** "I am a(n) *word-here*, so I'm sorry but I cannot eat anything with eggs in it. No Karen, I also cannot drink your homemade honey-milkshake - as I said, I follow a restrictive *word-here* diet."

*If no word exists purely for a diet, but does for a lifestyle that doesn't use animal produce (e.g. no wool, or other products that don't involve killing the animal); that word would be a sufficient alternative.*

For clarity, the person could:

- Eat beef
- Eat pork
- Not drink milk
- Not eat eggs
- Eat gelatin
- Eat blood products, so long as the blood was extracted from a slaughtered animal.
- Eat vegetables
- Eat fruit
- Eat any other non-animal products

*Just to avoid any comments asking about the realistic popularity of this "specific" diet; this is something that is not entirely uncommon. Especially as children learn where milk comes from, some make the decision that milk is not for them - but only for calfs. As such, I believe it's likely there is a term that exists to describe it.*

Comment: Do you have any hard evidence that such a diet exists beyond a few children's fads? It's certainly something I've never come across despite an interest in related topics, nor do I know of a reason (ethical for example) why such a diet would be desirable

Comment: @ChrisH I'm afraid nothing beyond similar questions being asked on "less good QA sites". There's a similar question on ELL, however the answers there "meatatarian" and "carnivore" neglect that meat is not the main part of the diet. It could be that this isn't a known term, and there is no technical way to name such a diet (the way that we can generate a name for any new chemical, by it's properties. e.g. di-hydrogen mon[o]-oxide) - which would of course be a perfectly acceptable answer. But I was hoping at least, there'd be a general way for diets like this to be specified (e.g ovo-vegetarian)

Comment: The problem is that most fruits and vegetables are alive (so to speak) before they are plucked. So *not living* isn't necessarily a sufficient criterion. Perhaps if you only ate those fruits and vegetables that had stopped growing and metabolizing. . .